# Building SPA app in AngularJS vs plain JavaScript - which Boostrap to choose for styling?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

Question may seem weird, but I want to build the Single Page Application with Responsive Web Design technique in two separate ways (too see and learn the differences between using framework vs plain programming language):

- with AngularJS + Boostrap
- with plain JavaScript + Boostrap

I don't want to use jQuery explicitly but I read, that Boostrap requires it to work properly. However AngularJS has it's own kind of implementation of jQuery, so instead of Boostrap it has to be Boostrap UI (to exclude conflict with jQuery).

How to do it then, to make CSS code very similar in both ways (using Angular vs plain JS), when Angular "prefers" Boostrap UI rather than Boostrap? Is **Boostrap UI** CSS code different than CSS code in **Boostrap** (I mean using their classes to style HTML elements)?

I want to have very similar or pretty identic CSS code in both ways. So, is it better then to use Boostrap UI when coding SPA with plain JS, because it's preffered for Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Angular UI does'nt contains the Bootstrap CSS : it's just a rewriting of some Bootstrap JS components without JQuery and with support of Angular JS directives.

You must include the "real" bootstrap.css file, and so your css code will be identical

Comment: So within plain JavaScript i can use "normal" Bootstrap (with it's jQuery stuff) and within Angular i have to use Boostrap UI with some "normal" Bootstrap **.css** files? And then I will have pretty the same overall CSS styling on both applications, including RWD?

Comment: Yes. And if you doesn't use the [Bootstrap javascript components](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/), you don't need JQuery. in your "Vanilla" SPA